# API key is not check that metadata react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api-key, react-native-maps

Hy I'm using `react-native-maps` first time I install and also configure it properly but when I run the app is display the following error:

```
API key not found. Chech that <Meta-data android:name:".." ...... is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

I try to clean the cache, clean gradlew, but didn't solve me.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.dateapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.xxxxxxxxxx"
     android:value="xxxxxxxxxx"/>
     
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Does someone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.dateapp">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
    />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
   <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="Your Google API Key Here"/>
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

You can't change the literal "API_KEY" in android:name, Set the android:name as "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"

and install build again